# Is the following language decidable? L = {<M> : M(x) is a Turing machine with running time bounded by 100|x|^2 + 200}

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines

L = {<M> : M(x) is a Turing machine with running time bounded by 100|x|^2 + 200}

I think L is undecidable but I can't solve that. Please help me prove it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this just the halting problem?

Answer (score -1):

The language L is decidable because it's property is related to the structure of the turing machine. In other words, it doesn't satisfy the third condition of the Rice's theorem which states that an undecidable property must be related to the language of the turing machine and not the structure of the machine.